# Ptrace - communication with child process

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

I would like to use `ptrace` in the following way (pseudocode):

child:

```
    foo();
    now that foo is done parent should use ptrace to change things
    parent did what he wanted to do
    bar();
```

parent:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
    //child
    exec(child_program)
else
    //parent
    attach ptrace
    let child run
    use ptrace to modify it's data
    let child continue
```

1. How should the child communicate with parent that it has completed `foo` and is ready to be modified? `raise(SIGSTOP)` maybe?
2. How should the parent wait for child to run `foo`?

I think we can assume that no SIGSTOP is raised before `pthread` should be used.

Comment: You should start a debugger session in strace environment. There you can see how the debugger manipulates the traced process and how it is interacting with SIGCHLD and other signals.

Comment: If `foo` is a shared library function, you can use `LD_PRELOAD` to load a shared object with your alternate implementation. Otherwise, you'll need to hope that `foo` isn't inlined anywhere and your executable has debug information.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo foo is just some function in C defined in the child program, not a shared library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to modify the registers of he traced process at some point in the execution. You should probably try to clarify your question because it's not really clear what you really want to achieve: why do you want to modify the registers in the first place. What do you expect to find in the registers? Why do you want to change those values?

Are you sure you do not want to communicate with sockets and/or shared memory instead? You should probably give a more details example to explain what you're trying to do.

### Breakpoint in the existing code

You have this code in the traced process:

```
foo();
// You want to modify something there.
bar();
```

Between `foo()` and `bar()` it's really not clear what is in the registers. Let's say we are using x86_64.

If you break when `foo` returns:

- EAX contains the return value of `foo` (if any) which is ignored in your caller anyway (so it does not make much sense to  modify it);
- callee-saved registers might contain some value from the caller but you would have to mess around with DWARF informations to try to make some sense out of it;
- caller-saved registers will not contain anything useful (but you might use DWARF unwinding information to find some other data which makes sense in the caller).

Breaking at the call site of `bar` (either in the caller or at the beginning of `bar`) might be slightly more interesting to you because you have access to the parameters of `bar`. You can modify them in you tracer process and you can even force a return call with a value if you want to.

### Raising signals

Another solution is to raise a signal:

```
foo();
raise(SIGTRAP);
bar();
```

As before, it's not clear what is in the registers and you may have to use DWARF to try to locate interesting data (which might or might not work).

A (possibly) cleaner solution would be to raise the exceptions with an instruction:

```
int     $3
```

The problem is that if your program is not running under the tracer, it will die.

### Add a hook for the tracer

A somewhat cleaner solutions is to add another function between `foo` and `bar`:

```
foo();
int res = delegate_to_tracer(x, y, z);
bar();
```

where `delegate_to_tracer` can be stubbed as:

```
int delegate_to_tracer(int x, int y, int z)
{
  // No-op implementation used when there is no tracer:
  return 0;
}
```

You can now add a breakpoint at the beginning of this function in order to handle it's functionality in the tracer:

- you can access the parameters;
- you can modify them;
- you can force a return with a given return value.

Another similar solution is to use static tracepoints ([SDT](https://lwn.net/Articles/330402/), [UST](http://lttng.org/man/3/lttng-ust/v2.7/)) but it probably does not make much sense to try to modify data from them.

### Faking a system call

You can use a system call in order to communicate with the tracer:

- either by using a [unused system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unimplemented.2.html) (`NR_tuxcall`?)
- either by using a unused system call number (but it might become used at some point);
- or by squatting an existing one.

The idea is that if this does not runs under your tracer, the system call will fail with `SIGSYS` (or other). However, under your tracer, you will intercept the system call and handle it yourself.

Making a tuxcall:

```
movq    $184, %rax # tuxcall
movq    $42,  %edi # param1
syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>I might be misunderstanding it, but is there any specific reason that you're wanting to use `ptrace` for what looks like IPC (Interprocess communication)? `ptrace` on Linux is *generally poorly suited* for IPC, and you should not really be using it to modify data in the child process.</del>



<del>If you want your child process to communicate with the parent, there are a multitude of different ways of achieving said tasks (ie. Unix Domain sockets, Pipes, Semaphores, Shared Memory), I suggest you look into them before attempting to do IPC using `ptrace`.</del>

**Edit:**

You could use a semaphore to let the parent wait for the child (see `sem_overview` in the Linux man pages) and do what you need to do. You could create a named semaphore using `sem_open` and have the child and wait for it in the parent, having the child notify the semaphore upon the completion of the said task.

Alternatively, make the traced child process use a breakpoint instruction which will stop it through `SIGTRAP` allowing you to `wait` on it and then do what you need to do. I believe a similar approach is used by GDB for debugging (patching instructions). If you're using x86, the following code should work for emitting a breakpoint instruction in your code:

```
asm volatile ("int3;")
```

May I also suggest using `process_vm_writev` instead of `ptrace` functions for  writing process memory (`PTRACE_POKETEXT`) since they can do bulk reads/writes to process memory.

For further reference, I think [debuggers_part2_code](https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/tree/master/2011/debuggers_part2_code) is a good example of how to roll your own debugging tools.

Comment: No, I want to use `ptrace` to modify memory of the child (use `PTRACE_POKETEXT` and `PTRACE_SETREGS`). Communication (of some sort) is only needed because memory/registers should be changed at specific moment in execution (in the pseudocode after `foo` and before `bar`)


Using gdb terminology I would like to put a breakpoint in the child code, let it  run untill it reaches it, then (using `ptrace`) modify this and that and then let the child continue.

Comment: Then use a semaphore as I suggested, or make the ptraced process use a breakpoint instruction, and issue a `wait` on it, which should trigger once the instruction is hit and the processed has received `SIGTRAP`.

Comment: I edited my question to provide more information, hopefully it'll be of help. I think semaphores would still be a better solution, but if you want a GDB-like approach, just use your architecture's trap instruction using inline asm in the place where you want to have a breakpoint.

Comment: You would need to use `PTRACE_CONT` to continue execution of the child process after you're done messing with it.